# how to automatically re-operate python script file if the process was over or die?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys, python-os

I'm really novice about Python, so I don't know exactly how to construct the logic.

This is my code:

**a.py**

```
import time

def main()
    while i < 10:
    i = i + 1
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

This will print 1, 2, 3, 4 ...... 11 sequentially. However, if the code would be terminated in the middle of executing, like print 1, 2, 3, 4 and then crash, how can I make the program start again?

I thought of a way to do it myself by importing the program as a module and checking whether it has crashed. A bit like the following pseudo-code:

```
import a

while check the a(python file):
    if a is not operating:
        a.main()
    else:
        pass
```

Another question I have is that I want to time the code when I want to stop.

Comment: So basically you want to restart the process automatically no matter whether it exited gracefully or crashed? What about the state of the application, to be resumed or to be restarted?

Comment: Normally it should be operated on OS level (restart if process died) and to continue execution you should save state every iteration.

Comment: yes, i want all whether resuming or restart @Thu Yein Tun

Comment: how? I really didn't get it. of curse, I searched it, but how construct entire code? @Olvin Roght

Comment: There are two ways I can think of. One is to create a systemd service, and the other is to use something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), both of which supports auto restarting in case of failure.

Comment: thanks I'll try it. @ Thu Yein Tun

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following code,although I'm not sure if this will help you solve the problem

```
import time

count = 0

def compute_number():
    for i in xrange(10):
        print ('count number: %s' % str(i+1))
        time.sleep(1)
    raise Exception("a", "b")

def main():  
    print ("AutoRes is starting")
    print ("Respawning")

    global count

    if count < 3:
        try:
           count += 1
           compute_number()
        except Exception, e:
           print (e)
           main()
       finally:
           print ('success')

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    main()
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I think version is different. "except Exception, e:" this code would get error